# how to print the numbers up to 10 that are not in an array?

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

I have an array, with values (2,3,4) inside, as an example, but it may be null.
Is there any way I can print out the numbers up to 10, but not those inside the array, ex: (1, 5, 6, ... 10) ?
I tried this: but it got messy:

```
foreach ($locuri as $k) {
  for ($i=1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
    if ($k == $i) {
      continue;
    } else {
      echo $i;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Which array is that? And can you define "messy"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

$array = [2,3,4];

//go through numbers from 1 to 10 and store it as $i
for ($i=0; $i <= 10; $i++) {
    //if $i is not in array echo it, the "!" changes the boolean value
    if ( !(in_array($i, $array)) ) {
        echo $i;
    }
}

?>
```

Let me know if you need any more explanation because the code looks pretty self-explanatory

Comment: Your answer is a python code, it is a php code requested.

Comment: sorry haha, I will fix that.

Comment: Read questions and tags carefully

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```php
for ($i=1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
  foreach ($locuri as $k) {
    if ($k == $i) {
      $found = true;
    }
  }
  if($found == false) echo $i;
  $found=false;
}
```